# How to interpret the template function signature of backtrace in GDB?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gdb

The output of backtrace of GDB is pretty messy, especially for template.

For instance:

```
Thread 2 (LWP 100146 of process 1245):
#0  thr_new () at thr_new.S:3
#1  0x000000080025c3da in _pthread_create (thread=0x7fffdfffd880, attr=<optimized out>, start_routine=0x205500 <void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >*> >(void*)>, arg=0x8007fa8e0) at /usr/src/lib/libthr/thread/thr_create.c:188
#2  0x0000000000204e40 in std::__1::thread::thread<void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >*, void>(void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >::*&&)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >*&&) ()
#3  0x0000000000204309 in std::__1::future<void> std::__1::__make_async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0> >(std::__1::__async_func<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>&&) ()
#4  0x00000000002035ea in std::__1::future<std::__1::__invoke_of<std::__1::decay<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>::type>::type> std::__1::async<func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0>(std::__1::launch, func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&)::$_0&&) ()
#5  0x0000000000203462 in func2(std::__1::atomic<long>&) ()
#6  0x0000000000206f18 in main::$_1::operator()() const ()
#7  0x0000000000206eed in void std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::__execute<>(std::__1::__tuple_indices<>) ()
#8  0x0000000000206ea5 in std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::operator()() ()
#9  0x0000000000206df3 in std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::__execute() ()
#10 0x0000000000207183 in void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1> >*> >(void*) ()
#11 0x000000080025c776 in thread_start (curthread=0x8007de500) at /usr/src/lib/libthr/thread/thr_create.c:292
#12 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffdfffe000
```

In frame #8, there are three pairs of parentheses, `std::__1::__async_func<main::$_1>::operator()() ()` what do they mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame #8 doesn't have debug info, so GDB can't accurately describe it.

Consider this test case:

```
struct Foo {
  int operator()(void) {
    return 1;  // line 3
  }
};

int main()
{
  return Foo()();
}
```

When compiled with `g++ -g t.cc` and at breakpoint on line 3, this is what GDB displays:

```
Breakpoint 1, Foo::operator() (this=0x7fffffffdcff) at t.cc:3
3       return 1;
(gdb) bt 
#0  Foo::operator() (this=0x7fffffffdcff) at t.cc:3
#1  0x0000555555555139 in main () at t.cc:10
```

But compile the same source without `-g`, set a breakpoint on `_ZN3FooclEv`, and this is what you will see:

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555140 in Foo::operator()() ()
(gdb) bt 
#0  0x0000555555555140 in Foo::operator()() ()
#1  0x0000555555555139 in main ()
```

The first two sets of parenthesis come from demangling the symbol:

```
c++filt _ZN3FooclEv
Foo::operator()()
```

The third set is added by GDB because the symbol being displayed is in the `.text` section and is assumed to be a function.